# Laravel Cache Not Clearing

Tags: laravel, caching

I was getting some strange 503 errors with some Laravel 5.4 requests so I was looking into the cache and noticed it was quite big.  I tried to clear it out but that did not seem to help.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
composer dump-autoload
cd storage/framework
storage/framework$ du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr

28G     ./cache
28G     .
24M     ./sessions
856K    ./views
8.0K    ./testing
```

The 28G size of the cache makes me think there's something else going on.
I'm not sure if my 503 errors are due to the cache size, but something seems off here.  Any reason why the cache isn't clearing?

Comment: I am using redis as my laravel cache driver. I also see that the cache entries are from 6 months ago.  Are these safe to delete rm -rf storage/framework/cache ?

Comment: I would like to know the same, did you go ahead with the rm -rf?

Answer (score 0):

try this one. run this in your cli.

1st

```
 redis-cli
```

2nd

```
flushall
```

Comment: Still the same.  Cache appears to be operating normally though.